# Help with thinking MVC while programming

Tags: python, model-view-controller, class

I am trying to convert this application i created into MVC style.
This is my original source:

http://pastebin.com/xELEt0yi

Below is my attempt to create above source into MVC

http://pastebin.com/B21cskhA

My issues:

- I don't understand how to call from
  another class. I tried making
  "_*init _*" under each class to call model, view or control. Unfortunately
  i ran into this error:
  *RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded*
- I thought about maybe turning my
  data into dictionaries but i don't
  know if i am creating that correctly.
  The attempted MVC source above has
  the dictionaries i am referring too.
- last thing is in my source my view
  can go two ways. If "y" does
  something if "n" does something else.
  How do i go about letting my
  controller switching from those,
  would it be something like this:
  http://pastebin.com/Z9pp1L3g

Can someone look at my MVC source and guide me to completing this task.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is required to use MVC in such a simple code. It will unnecessarily complicate your code.

Comment: The question seems a little broad. Typically you call from another class by including using an include type keyword. The source needs to know the data from the file you are invoking with a method.

Comment: This is true, my application before MVC conversion works perfect. No issues at all. I am trying to get in the mind set of writing programs as a OOP style. 
i am rather close to completing this as a MVC style source but i just don't know how to complete the issues i stated above.

Comment: " don't understand how to call from another class. I tried making `__init__` under each class to call model, view or control. Unfortunately i ran into this error: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".  Focus on just this.  Rewriting a non-MVC program into MVC is hard.  It's easier to start from nothing.  Please focus on just one thing and create a new question on this problem and this problem only.  Post just the relevant code that doesn't work.  No links to off-site code.  Not all the code you own.  Focus on just this one problem -- we can help with that.

Comment: I don't see a reason for this to be MVC. What's the impetus for that move?

Comment: Well i pretty much was able to get it into the form of MVC, http://pastebin.com/iy3FE9yD 
(S.Lott Can you teach me how you highlighted '__init__') now i just don't understand how to call from other classes (ie. Return), but i'll figure that out. So turning this into MVC wasn't impossible, but i agree not something that needs to be turned into MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Application using MVC:

http://pastebin.com/0CiTqiwu

I was rather close in completing this task. I had it as

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View()
    def main(self):
        self.model.filename()
        self.view.tcpdump()
```

instead of:

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = View()
    def main(self):
        self.view.filename()
        self.view.tcpdump()
```

Which after i changed it to that with the help of a co-worker, the script turned out to work perfect. Operation turn simple tcpdump script to MVC style, Success!

Thanks everyone for the help~